# Call to a member function paginate() on array in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Here is my code in laravel,

```
use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator;

$result = DB::connection('mysql')->select("select * from login_master")->paginate(5);
```

Its showing Call to a member function paginate() on array. How to user `paginate()` in this code.

Comment: Its Duplicate ! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30321497/how-to-use-pagination-in-laravel-5-with-raw-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
DB::connection('mysql')->table("login_master")->paginate(5);
```

If using Eloquent:

```
LoginMaster::paginate(5);
```

Comment: thanks for answer, but is there any way to use for raw query as i showed in my question

Comment: Is there a reason for this, do you have a more complex query?

Comment: yes exactly, some join and complex queries are there thats why@Calin Blaga

Comment: then here is a sample which isn't using raw query, but I'm pretty sure you can adapt you query: DB::connection('mysql')
        ->table('users')
        ->leftJoin('payments', 'users.id', '=', 'payments.userID')
        ->paginate(5);