# I want to use pagination with laravel Raw query builder

Tags: laravel

Here is my Raw query

```
$searchData=DB::select('SELECT * FROM hostretreats WHERE (furnishing_type= "'.$typesearchkeyword.'" OR prop_type="'.$typesearchkeyword.'") AND approved = 1');
```

Help me how can I fix it?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30321497/how-to-use-pagination-in-laravel-5-with-raw-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rewrite select query with DB methods.

```
$searchData = DB::table('hostretreats')
    ->where(function($query) use ($typesearchkeyword){
        $query
            ->where('furnishing_type', $typesearchkeyword)
            ->orWhere('prop_type', $typesearchkeyword);
    })
    ->where('approved', 1)
    ->paginate(10);
```

Comment: i have applied your answer but i am getting this error-

"Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection::from()"

Comment: Sorry, `table()` instead of `from()`. I corrected the answer.

Comment: yes.... thanks man, execute it and getting which I want you saved lots of my time..i really appreciate by your answer..thanks