# I Create mysql query but i not get pagination how to use laravel paginate in this query

Tags: laravel

I've created MySQL query for searching results. The query works properly but if I use laravel pagination on this query I get an error

> Call to a member function paginate() on array ,

How to solve this with pagination?

```
$search = \DB::SELECT("SELECT l.*, 
       r.id          AS reservation_id, 
       r.status      AS res_status, 
       r.start_date, 
       r.end_date, 
       Avg(r.rating) AS rating 
FROM   listings l 
       LEFT JOIN reservations r ON r.listing_id = l.id 
WHERE  ( ( Cast('" . $search_date . "' AS date) NOT BETWEEN r.start_date AND r.end_date )  OR r.status = 'Cancel' ) 
       AND l.city_id = $city_id 
       AND l.persons >= $guests 
       AND l.listing_type_id = $type 
GROUP  BY l.id 
ORDER  BY r.rating DESC 
");
```

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: Laravel Version 5.5

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use pagination in laravel 5 with Raw query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30321497/how-to-use-pagination-in-laravel-5-with-raw-query)

Answer (score 0):

`DB::select()` will return an array. You could probably convert your query to a Query Builder and then use `paginate()` on it. For example:

```
$search = DB::table('listings')
    ->selectRaw('listings.*, reservations.id AS reservation_id, reservations.status AS res_status, reservations.start_date, reservations.end_date, AVG(reservations.rating) as rating')
    ->leftJoin('reservations', 'reservations.listing_id', 'listings.id')
    ->whereRaw("(CAST(? AS date) NOT BETWEEN reservations.start_date AND reservations.end_date) or reservations.status = 'Cancel'", [$search_date])
    ->where('listings.city_id', '=', $city_id)
    ->where('listings.persons', '>=', $guests)
    ->where('listings.listing_type_id', '=', $type)
    ->groupBy('listings.id')
    ->orderBy('reservations.rating', 'DESC')
    ->paginate(10);
```